# Player movement in visual basic causes pause

Tags: vb.net, game-physics

I have created my own player movement in Visual Basic, so I have a picturebox that I imported a picture into and then I created movement with the arrow keys through:
Public Class Form1

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    If e.KeyData = Keys.Right Then
        Player.Left += 3
    End If

    If e.KeyData = Keys.Left Then
        Player.Left -= 3
    End If

    If e.KeyData = Keys.Up Then
        Player.Top -= 3
    End If

    If e.KeyData = Keys.Down Then
        Player.Top += 3
    End If
    Refresh()

End Sub
```

The only problem is, there is a small little pause before the movement. I don't know if you guys realize, but the time when the Key is down, the guy pauses a bit, as if he knows he has to move to up/down/left/right, but can't. Eventually he finally moves to the designated area after the pause. I can't seem to find out why this is...

Answer (score 1):

Its the velocity of repetition while writing. The same if you open word and hold a letter. First writes one, and after some time it repeats. You should use a SDK to make a game instead of doing that, but this solves your problem:

Instead of using that event, use a timer and check the keys that are pressed. This will allow you to move in too directions at the same time (diagonally) or more thing that requiere pressing more that one key at the same time.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If GetKeyState(87) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(38) < 0 Then : Player.Top -= iVel
    ElseIf GetKeyState(65) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(37) < 0 Then : Player.Left -= iVel
    ElseIf GetKeyState(68) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(39) < 0 Then : Player.Left += iVel
    ElseIf GetKeyState(83) < 0 OrElse GetKeyState(40) < 0 Then : Player.Top += iVel
    End If 
End Sub
```

I recomend you a very low interval (like 20 or so) for the Timer. The function used to get the keys pressed you have to define it:

```
Private Declare Function GetKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal nVirtKey As IntPtr) As Short
```

Hope this helps. By the way, the code I posted will work with arrow keys and WASD keys.

Comment: The only error I get is kreypressed not defined and iVel not declared, please help?

Comment: @JackC. Dont use `keypressed`, was just something that I used on my code. And `iVel` is just an Integer to determine the velocity it moves, just change it to the number you want.